# Warning ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: this request accesses system indices

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Eu estou recebendo um Warning ao tentar obter todos os índices no Elastic após a última atualização da versão.

Warning.

> C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py:190:
> ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: this request accesses system indices:
> [.apm-agent-configuration, .apm-custom-link, .kibana_1, .kibana_2,
> .kibana_task_manager_1, .kibana_task_manager_2,
> .kibana_task_manager_3], but in a future major version, direct access
> to system indices will be prevented by default warnings.warn(message,
> category=ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning)

Ocorre quando eu faço

```
for index in es.indices.get('*'):
```

Elasticsearch versão 7.10

Essa pergunta também foi feita no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080394/elasticsearchdeprecationwarning-this-request-accesses-system-indices)

Comment: Conforme a documentação https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-highlights.html#deprecate-rest-api-access-to-system-indices e a própria mensagem de erro (que na verdade é um warning e não um erro), o acesso da API REST aos índices está sendo descontinuando (obsoleto). A maioria das solicitações da API REST que tentam acessar os índices do sistema retornará essa mensagem, no seu caso é essa (provavelmente) ` GET _cat/[indices,...]` (ou uma das outras rotas)

Comment: eu não entendo de Elastic, mas creio que agora o caminho deva ser por aqui https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-index.html

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, até já tinha visto isso, mas a documentação não dar um exemplo básico de como contorna isso.

Comment: Não é "contornar", tem que mudar tudo :( ... pelo que entendi (se é que entendi) só tendo os indices para acessar agora, mas realmente não entendo disso para afirmar como obter previamente.

Comment: Você está utilizando a biblioteca `elasticsearch` para acessar ao Elastic. Se teve mudanças na API do Elastic, provavelmente a biblioteca sofreu alguma atualização também (ou ela não suporta a versão mais nova). Tente atualizá-la.

Comment: Olá @Woss, isso ai esta descrito no [primeiro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484595/warning-elasticsearchdeprecationwarning-this-request-accesses-system-indices#comment905042_484595) e tem o link que aponta quais urls da api foram descontinuadas e a explicação sobre que terá que ter os indices. O que ele quer é saber como fazer isso.

Comment: Não, me referia à biblioteca do Python mesmo: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/index.html

Comment: @Woss, a biblioteca foi atualizada para ultima versão (elasticsearch/reference/7.10), mas pelo que entendi não tem mais como usar o (*) para retorna todos os indeces da API, teria que mandar todos os nome dos indeces separados por (;), mas nem sempre eu tenho o nome de todos por eles ser criados dinamicamente.